# Aggregate data and JOIN two tables without corresponding key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: area_costs and products_shipped.

area_costs contains the costs per area, i.e. courier costs, transportation.

```
---------------------
|year|week|area|cost|
---------------------
```

The table products_shipped contains all the products that were shipped to customers:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|product_id|area|customer_id|drop_id|date_id|product_price|
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Now as stated above, there is no matching key to join these tables. I want to do a calculation that essentially takes the cost per area and divides it by the number of drops per area to get the average spent per drop. If all the information was available in one table I would probably type:

```
SELECT area, SUM(cost) / COUNT(drop_id) AS spent_per_drop FROM full_table GROUP by AREA
```

Is there any way to do this with the information provided?

Sample data:

area_costs:

```
---------------------
|year|week|area|cost|
|2016|20  |mel |5000|
|2016|20  |syd |7500|
|2016|20  |bri |3000|
|2016|21  |mel |5200|
|2016|21  |syd |7400|
---------------------
```

products_shipped:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|product_id|area|customer_id|drop_id       |date_id |
|515       |syd |100        |515-syd-100-01|20160607|
|515       |syd |102        |515-syd-102-12|20160607|
|508       |mel |103        |508-mel-103-03|20160607|
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Let's say that I do a SUM() on week 20 in the area_costs table:

```
SELECT area, SUM(cost_actual) FROM area_costs GROUP BY area
```

I will get 7500 for Syd. I want to divide that by the number of drop_id in the products_shipped table, which in the sample data gives me the count of 2. Hence, the result should be 7500 / 2 = 3750.

I can do this in 2 queries, getting both aggregates separately and then dividing the results, but there's no way this is a flexible solution.

My question is: Is it possible to do this in one query?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: If you have no matching key, then there's no calculation to be done. You appear to have an "area" field in both.

Comment: Isn't `area` the common column in both tables? It would be better if you can give some sample data explaining the output you expect

Comment: Sorry, forgot to state this - the area_costs contains values in the areas that are not necessarily actual areas in the products_shipped table; sadly deeming my calculation biassed if I use area as the common field.

Comment: @Adrian - You got to give some sample data and what do you expect in output.

Comment: @Utsav I am trying to get the total SUM() of the area_costs and then divide it by the total count of drops in the products_shipped table. I can do it in 2 queries, basically getting the SUM() from area_costs and the COUNT() of drops, then divide it. Is this possible in 1 query?

Answer (score 1):

Because your sample data doesn't really demonstrate how a simple inner join could go wrong, I am opting for just doing two aggregations of the `area_costs` and `products_shipped` tables in separate subqueries.  I then join together these two subqueries to get the final result.  Note that I used a `LEFT JOIN` just in case an `area` in `area_costs` does not have any entries in `products_shipped`.  In this case, I display `NA` for the spent-per-drop statistic.

```
SELECT t1.area,
    CASE WHEN t2.drop_count IS NULL
         THEN "NA"
         ELSE CAST((t1.cost_sum / t2.drop_count) AS VARCHAR)
    END AS spent_per_drop
FROM
(
    SELECT area, SUM(cost_actual) AS cost_sum
    FROM area_costs
    GROUP BY area
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT area, COUNT(*) AS drop_count
    FROM products_shipped
    GROUP BY area
) t2
    ON t1.area = t2.area
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tim. The query given gives me the same results when I solely query on the area_costs table (SUM(cost)), since the products_shipped table is much bigger, giving me a larger SUM() when I join on area. What I essentially try to do is get the total SUM() of the costs from area_costs and divide that by the total COUNT() of drop_id in products_shipped. Example: total costs from area_costs retrieved by a SUM() then divided by the total count of products_shipped. Is this possible?

Comment: Update your question with clear sample input and desired output.

Comment: Edited my question.